# string in a string with template literals

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to make a string in a string with a template literal in javascript ecma6. Is it possible to add the double or single quotes to the tamplate litaral output in the string. 
i came accross this problem using the output of a directory in a string from path as a string.

```
let input = "C:\users\document"
```

i want to `child.stdin.write('athom project --run "C:\users\document" \n')`

i came to this `child.stdin.write('athom project --run "' +`${input}`+ '"C:\users\document \n')`

isnt there a neater way to do it in ecma6 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is delimited by backticks (`).  You're currently trying to delimit it with single quotes.

Do this:

```
let input = "C:\users\document";
child.stdin.write(`athom project --run "${input}"\n`);
```

Comment: I wrote this :    i came to this child.stdin.write('athom project --run "' + `${input}`+ '"C:\users\document \n') . The code editor deleted the back tics around ${input} . And still does. The answer you gave was what i was looking for.